# Factoring variables in R

Tags: r, statistics

The variable `Language` contains 33 different languages

```
factor_language_var <- factor(Data$Language)
summary(factor_language_var)
 ar    ca    cs    da    de    el    en en-gb en-GB    es    fi    fr    hi    hu    id    it    ja 
4     5     4     5   231     1 12067   229     2   121     8   206     2     2    34    45    48
```

etc...

If i just factor the variable it obviously creates 33 levels which I don't need.
How to specifically select languages (values) and create a level out of them?

Specifically, I need `en`, `en-gb`, and `en-GB` (English) to form Level 1; `nl` (Dutch) – Level 2; `msa` (Malay) – Level 3; `ru` (Russian) – Level 4; and all other languages combined as a reference category.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The switch function can be used but is unfortunately not vectorized so one needs to "sapply" the arguments to it:

```
x <- c("en","en-gb","en-GB","nl","msa","ru","other1","other2")

sapply(x, function(z) switch(z,
   'en'=, 'en-gb' =, 'en-GB'= "Level 1",
   'nl'=   "Level 2",
   'msa' = "Level 3",
   'ru' =  "Level 4", 
        "All others") )
```

You get a named vector (suitable for tabulation) as a result:

```
          en        en-gb        en-GB           nl          msa 
   "Level 1"    "Level 1"    "Level 1"    "Level 2"    "Level 3" 
          ru       other1       other2 
   "Level 4" "All others" "All others" 

 table( sapply(x, function(z) switch(z,
        'en'=, 'en-gb' =, 'en-GB'= "Level 1",
        'nl'= "Level 2",
        'msa' = "Level 3",
        'ru' ="Level 4", "All others") ) )

#All others    Level 1    Level 2    Level 3    Level 4 
#         2          3          1          1          1
```

This uses the character-argument version of switch. It's a bit cleaner than the nested `ifelse` approach. Probably also a lot faster since you don;t need to create a bunch of accessory vectors.

If you want to preserve NA_character_ values as NA's then this succeeds:

```
> sapply(x, function(z) switch(z,
+        'en'=, 'en-gb' =, 'en-GB'= "Level 1",
+        'nl'= "Level 2",
+        'msa' = "Level 3",
+        'ru' ="Level 4",
+         'NA' = "NA",
+                "All others") )
          en        en-gb        en-GB           nl          msa 
   "Level 1"    "Level 1"    "Level 1"    "Level 2"    "Level 3" 
          ru       other1       other2         <NA> 
   "Level 4" "All others" "All others"         "NA"
```

Comment: Much like my (now deleted) answer, this clobbers NA values. I haven't figured a way around that yet.

Comment: When I put an NA in the inputs I get "All others" (which I suppose might or might not be desired.) I'll post an alternate:

Comment: @BondedDust Thanks! This is more complicated than I expected it to be. NAs are not a problem since I cleaned my data beforehand.

Comment: I think the `switch` function was originally designed for program control and so the lack of vectorization reflects a similarity with the `if(){}else{}` flow-control construct rather than the `ifelse()` function.

Answer (score 1):

unless I'm missing something obvious, you're  basically asking how to define the levels of a factor?

Your example data doesn't have all 33 levels that you state in the question.  However, I added some that you referenced.   Essentially you need to create a variable in a dataframe that has the information about what factor level each language should be  - then make a factor out of that variable.

```
langs <- c("ar", "ca" ,"cs","da","de","el","en", "en-gb", "en-GB", "es", "fi", "fr", "hi", "hu", "id", "it", "ja", "msa", "nl", "ru") 
langs1 <- data.frame(langs=langs)

langs1

langs1$mylevels <- ifelse(langs=="en" | langs=="en-gb" | langs=="en-GB", "level1", 
                        ifelse(langs=="nl", "level2", 
                               ifelse(langs=="msa", "level3",
                                      ifelse(langs=="ru", "level4",
                                             "reference")))) 

langs1$mylevels <- as.factor(langs1$mylevels)

str(langs1)  #you can see that mylevels has the languages referenced in different factor levels
```

Comment: And in one line with dplyr: 

    `langs1<-langs1 %>% mutate(levels=as.factor(ifelse(langs=="en" | langs=="en-gb" | langs=="en-GB","level1",ifelse(langs=="nl","level2",ifelse(langs=="msa","level3",ifelse(langs=="ru","level4","reference"))))))`